# Rails model_path routing error, no route matching "model.2"; should be "model/2"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

There seems to be something wrong with my routing paths. Normally I should be able to do something like `<%= link_to Profile, user_path(@user||current_user) %>` and I move on with my day. For whatever reason I'm failing to understand my `user_path` is not returning `/user/:id` like I would expect it to do. Instead it is returning `/user.:id`
To test this, I loaded a partial with the following code.

**app/view/users/_test.html.rb**

```
<%= @user %><br>
<%= @user.id %><br>
<%= link_to user_path(@user), user_path(@user) %><br>
<%= new_user_path %><br>
<%= edit_user_path(@user) %><br>
<%= url_for(@user) %>
```

This returned

**localhost:3000/test**

```
#<User:0x007fb6cd341f08>
1
/user.1
/users/new
/users/1/edit
/user.1
```

I can't figure out what is causing this to happen. The `edit_user_path(@user)` works perfectly, but the show doesn't. I have read the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) from top to bottom about three times and I can't figure it out. The closest I found to my problem was on an [old Rails 3.1 gem problem with Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1100), but I'm not even using the Devise gem (maybe I should be?).

Why is my route failing? I'm not really looking for a workaround (though I suppose I'd rather have a workaround than no solution), I want to understand why this is happening and fix it. What's going on?

My routes are pretty vanilla, nothing special going on there, but just in case the problem is there and I missed it, here it is.

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static#home'

  %w( 404 406 422 500 503 ).each do |code|
    get code, :to => "errors#show", :code => code 
  end 

  #USER PAGES
  get '/test' => 'users#test'
  get '/signup' => 'users#new'
  post '/user' => 'users#create'
  get '/user/list' => 'users#index'
  post '/user/' => 'users#update'
  get '/user/:id' => 'users#show'
  get 'profile', to: 'users#show'

  resources :users
end
```

Comment: You can try to run `rake routes` - it might give you/SO users an insights into how your routes are actually generated

Comment: You're actually defining a few of the routes twice: `resources :users` is all you need for the standard CRUD routing. This _could_ be the issue - somewhere, you may be overwriting the named pathway for `show`. I'd start by removing the duplicated routes, or adding a third argument linke `as: :the_paths_name` to the routes you're defining line by line.

Comment: Also, just to note, the output you're getting (i.e. `/user.1`) comes when passing an arg without a key to paths _not_ expecting an id parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest updating your routes as follows:

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static#home'

  %w( 404 406 422 500 503 ).each do |code|
    get code, :to => "errors#show", :code => code 
  end 

  #USER PAGES
  get '/test' => 'users#test'
  get 'profile', to: 'users#show', as: :user_profile

  resources :users
end
```

...as `resources :users` creates all of the routes I've removed.

The duplicates may have been overwriting a default path, causing the behaviour you're seeing - if you pass an object to a url helper that doesn't expect a parameter, you see the behaviour you're getting (i.e. `doesnt_have_an_id_path(@object) => /doesnt_have_an_id.1`).

I've also added a name to the user profile path to avoid this clashing. See if this works (perhaps one step at a time to get the cause and effect) - otherwise, try temporarily removing the profile route.

Re that path, you may have a problem in that the `users#show` action will expect an `:id` parameter, yet that route doesn't allow for one. This *might* be causing the current problem, though if not, may cause issues down the line.

Hope that fixes it - shout if you've any questions / feedback when you've tried it out.

Comment: Yep! This fixed it. Thanks so much! And now I know for the future.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it @Martin :)

Answer (score 1):

In your case the two conflicting routes are:

```
post '/user/' => 'users#update'
get '/user/:id' => 'users#show'
```

You are trying to use `user_path` helper method, thus you need to have `user` named route.
If you run `rake routes` for these two routes you will see this:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern         Controller#Action
  user POST /user(.:format)     users#create
       GET  /user/:id(.:format) users#show
```

The `Prefix` column shows you the named routes which are defined for your application. In this case Rails auto-generated named route `user` for POST `/user` endpoint. That means `user_path` will return /user instead of `/user/:id` as you expected. Rails generate routes like these when it sees a route definition without parameters. For example if you have `get /user/some/more` in your routes, Rails will auto-generate named route `user_some_more` for you and they you will be able to use `user_some_more_path` helper.

In order to fix your particular case you can stop rails from generating route for POST endpoint by doing this: `post '/user/', as: nil` and give GET endpoint a name you want: `get '/user/:id', as: 'user'`. Then you will be able to use `user_path(user)` to generate paths of format /user/:id.